# RHEL8 based system has multiple kernels but module will only load in one of them

Tags: sas, rhel8, kernel-modules

As the title says I have multiple kernels on my system

```
4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64
4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64
4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64
```

Issue is I am using mpt3sas on my system and when i installed it on `4.18.0-193.19.1` it was perfect.  Now on a later kernel I am seeing that kernel does't detect that module.  I can't modinfo it or modprobe it.  But when I attempt to install it it does detect that it's already installed.  It is in the `/lib/modules/4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64/weak-updates` & `/lib/modules/4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64/extra` directories if that makes a difference.

Any ideas on what I can do?  Should I uninstall it and reinstall it on the newer kernel?  I attempted to copy the directories & .ko files but that didn't make a different it seems.

EDIT:
I attempted to remove the old version in there and install it via dnf and now it seems I have two version installed on the system.  Here is the output of `modinfo mpt3sas`:

```
 modinfo mpt3sas                                                                                                                                              PLEX
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64/extra/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko
alias:          mpt2sas
version:        32.100.00.00
license:        GPL
description:    LSI MPT Fusion SAS 3.0 Device Driver
author:         Avago Technologies <MPT-FusionLinux.pdl@avagotech.com>
rhelversion:    8.2
srcversion:     7C68C3E1EC928FA96966F19
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000E6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000E5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000B2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000E2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000E1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000D1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000ACsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000ABsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000AAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000AFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000AEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000ADsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000095sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000094sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000097sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000096sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d0000007Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000002B1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000002B0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d0000006Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000087sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000086sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000085sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000084sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000083sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000082sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000081sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000080sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000065sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000064sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000077sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000076sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000074sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000072sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000070sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        scsi_transport_sas,raid_class
name:           mpt3sas
vermagic:       4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         ELRepo.org Secure Boot Key
sig_key:        E9:D4:71:CF:B4:FE:13:6C
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
signature:      94:52:91:50:DC:0D:4E:BF:96:69:4C:35:7C:37:99:60:49:7A:6E:E1:
                E6:6B:0F:C5:3B:C1:60:FF:81:B8:0B:60:72:26:0E:26:11:C4:8A:21:
                96:E9:2A:BF:A0:EA:60:40:2E:B4:1E:99:AB:B5:B7:A9:35:95:CC:31:
                1B:BF:72:2E:07:2C:D3:D9:F9:85:C4:94:01:C9:F4:73:A9:E9:A5:12:
                F5:65:79:B0:F5:54:E0:C5:CB:BC:1E:F5:28:5B:E1:A5:96:3B:12:7A:
                9D:E8:51:B5:D7:56:B2:7C:06:88:D2:6D:CD:69:DE:36:2D:D7:09:8F:
                79:B5:41:E6:5C:00:FD:89:E1:F6:6F:25:CC:2A:B6:AC:41:12:F7:80:
                CB:71:EE:22:4F:BF:E1:44:3A:29:5C:29:EF:76:99:63:34:47:EE:9F:
                35:63:5E:2A:EF:FD:30:5B:69:F7:F6:AD:E6:AF:0D:BD:69:D9:19:80:
                55:25:64:83:C4:41:AD:41:86:4B:CE:E5:73:61:83:F9:9E:86:7B:82:
                33:38:94:1A:D7:D3:A7:4A:A1:96:67:02:3E:7F:D5:02:2C:B3:27:10:
                AB:0F:B0:AA:A7:FD:18:5A:BC:04:8A:38:09:9A:FC:B9:35:54:5E:89:
                9E:AC:42:A7:90:DA:74:7E:05:D0:B3:79:37:7F:3E:16:82:4A:F8:DF:
                BD:CA:58:6D:80:15:1C:14:B0:38:7B:4D:48:6D:D9:EE:3C:AD:CF:DA:
                79:71:ED:2B:3A:5F:0F:7A:D8:BB:68:3B:27:6F:58:AA:A9:B1:E3:A8:
                C7:65:2A:56:1F:C4:16:3F:EE:B8:FE:27:85:5F:45:3B:53:73:1F:BC:
                9F:F5:88:78:50:87:30:33:25:30:D4:2D:62:45:CC:55:FF:15:C9:52:
                CF:1E:2F:30:6B:9D:39:20:6F:51:5C:F1:F4:33:16:03:ED:AB:7E:DF:
                EA:5B:E1:AB:A2:4E:CF:68:DF:94:F7:E3:E8:63:7F:AE:63:47:11:61:
                2C:9F:7F:95:06:D1:22:6C:BA:64:28:BF:D2:9A:66:E1:F7:59:68:33:
                A5:BE:14:DE:E8:DD:60:E5:D4:3F:34:15:F8:94:6B:4E:2D:1F:27:9E:
                5E:CF:5A:FD:45:70:77:CE:8E:D1:C9:7E:57:08:3F:73:F7:6A:18:86:
                2F:6E:8F:08:D1:FF:77:CC:50:FF:23:D6:D9:79:84:96:EE:68:D3:7F:
                BF:2D:D4:91:FE:5B:2E:2A:BA:E6:AC:10:E6:28:9A:AC:90:9F:87:43:
                BA:72:20:BF:8B:67:D9:84:1C:E6:A1:48:A4:1B:F1:85:46:7C:B4:44:
                43:71:1B:AB:5F:0B:65:02:FA:FC:4C:90
parm:           logging_level: bits for enabling additional logging info (default=0)
parm:           max_sectors:max sectors, range 64 to 32767  default=32767 (ushort)
parm:           missing_delay: device missing delay , io missing delay (array of int)
parm:           max_lun: max lun, default=16895  (ullong)
parm:           hbas_to_enumerate: 0 - enumerates both SAS 2.0 & SAS 3.0 generation HBAs
                  1 - enumerates only SAS 2.0 generation HBAs
                  2 - enumerates only SAS 3.0 generation HBAs (default=0) (ushort)
parm:           diag_buffer_enable: post diag buffers (TRACE=1/SNAPSHOT=2/EXTENDED=4/default=0) (int)
parm:           disable_discovery: disable discovery  (int)
parm:           prot_mask: host protection capabilities mask, def=7  (int)
parm:           enable_sdev_max_qd:Enable sdev max qd as can_queue, def=disabled(0) (bool)
parm:           max_queue_depth: max controller queue depth  (int)
parm:           max_sgl_entries: max sg entries  (int)
parm:           msix_disable: disable msix routed interrupts (default=0) (int)
parm:           smp_affinity_enable:SMP affinity feature enable/disable Default: enable(1) (int)
parm:           max_msix_vectors: max msix vectors (int)
parm:           irqpoll_weight:irq poll weight (default= one fourth of HBA queue depth) (int)
parm:           mpt3sas_fwfault_debug: enable detection of firmware fault and halt firmware - (default=0)
parm:           perf_mode:Performance mode (only for Aero/Sea Generation), options:
                0 - balanced: high iops mode is enabled &
                interrupt coalescing is enabled only on high iops queues,
                1 - iops: high iops mode is disabled &
                interrupt coalescing is enabled on all queues,
                2 - latency: high iops mode is disabled &
                interrupt coalescing is enabled on all queues with timeout value 0xA,
                default - default perf_mode is 'balanced' (int)
 root ~    $ modprobe mpt3sas                                                                                                                                             PLEX
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mpt3sas': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Comment: I was able to fix this by following these instructions:

https://www.networkshinobi.com/centos-8-with-lsi-sas2008/

Answer (score 0):

Kernel modules are specific to kernel versions and a new kernel requires that the module gets updated/recompiled as well.

When the original provider hasn't built the required new binary RPM package yet, install the source package and build your own binary RPM package that matches your new kernel i.e.

See for example https://www.ibm.com/docs/pt/ess-p8/5.1.0?topic=guide-instructions-updating-mpt3sas-driver

> Download the SRPM
>
> Rebuild the RPMs for the running kernel.
>
> ```
> rpmbuild --rebuild SRC_RPM_LOCATION/mpt3sas-13.100.00.00-1.el7_2.src.rpm
> ```
>
> This command creates two RPMs.
>
> Unload the current mpt3sas driver.
>
> ```
> rmmod mpt3sas
> ```
>
> Install the RPMs.
>
> ```
> rpm -Uvh /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/ppc64le/kmod-mpt3sas*rpm
> rpm -Uvh /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/ppc64le/mpt3sas*rpm
> ```
>
> Load the updated modules.
>
> ```
> modprobe mpt3sas
> ```
>
> Verify that the module is loaded.
>
> ```
> modinfo mpt3sas
> ```

Comment: Attempted to rebuild with this command but I only have the kmod driver, not the mpt3sas driver



`rpmbuild --rebuild kmod-mpt3sas-28.100.00.00-3.el8_2.elrepo.x86_64.rpm`

`Installing kmod-mpt3sas-28.100.00.00-3.el8_2.elrepo.x86_64.rpm`

`warning: kmod-mpt3sas-28.100.00.00-3.el8_2.elrepo.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID baadae52: NOKEY`

`error: source package expected, binary found`

`error: kmod-mpt3sas-28.100.00.00-3.el8_2.elrepo.x86_64.rpm cannot be installed`